# Import local python file as class

Tags: python

I have a Flask app created, and my folder structure looks like this:

```
-- Folder
  ---- app.py
  ---- page.py
  ---- __init__.py
```

I'm trying to reference page.py as a class, using:

```
from flask import render_template
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
import logging
import json
import requests
import os
import page as Page 

""" Initialise the app """
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But I get the error:

```
Cannot import 'page' due to syntax error 'invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 3)'pylint(syntax-error)
```

Where am I going wrong?

My class file looks like this:

```
class Page:
    def __init__(self, title, environ)
    self.title = title 
    self.environment = environ
```

I tried from .page import Page

but still got the error:

```
Cannot import 'page' due to syntax error 'invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 3)'pylint(syntax-error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to syntax error in line 3.

```
class Page:
    def __init__(self, title, environ) # no colon
    self.title = title # no indentation
    self.environment = environ
```

If this is how it looks like (as you have attached), there is no colon (`:`) and indention after def where it should belong. Therefore, your page.py should look something like:

```
class Page:
    def __init__(self, title, environ):
        self.title = title 
        self.environment = environ
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it - feel so stupid! I'm coming from C# where indentation etc isn't as critical.

Comment: I started with C first, so I feel you :) The indentation can be a real pain, you can always use `pylint yourcode.py` to check for any syntax-related errors in your code.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's these little things that are my biggest learning with Python

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
from .page import Page
```

Answer (score 0):

`page.py` cannot be referenced as a class as it is just a python file. I presume there is a class within this file called `Page`.

Therefore, you will need to import the `Page` class from the `page.py` file with the following syntax:

`from .page import Page`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having that error is because you aren't accessing the package first, you are trying to go straight to the module, but it doesn't work that way.
You have to access the package first, then the module, then the class and so on.

What you should have then is

```
from Folder.page import Page
```

or to work with relative path use

```
 from .page import Page
```

Hope this helps
One last piece of advice would be to use correcting naming patterns which means classes start with uppercase letters, that will make imports easier for you in the long run

```
class Page:
    def __init__(self, title, environ)
        self.title = title 
        self.environment = environ
```

Note the indentation change

Comment: did you try the initial option of `from Folder.page import Page`. Also correct the syntax error in your class, i have updated my answer to help